# riscv's custom instructions are not compiled gnu as, ld into the correct machine language

Tags: assembly, cross-compiling, gnu, ld, riscv

I want to run a custom instruction on the following RISC-V 32IM: custom_es32, which is an R-style instruction such as add, sub, etc. Only func7 is "1110001" different from add,sub, etc. I have used riscv-gnu-unknown-as to startup, S and disassemble them with riscv-gnu-unknown-as, opcode becomes 11010111 instead of 0110011 and func7 becomes 0000001 instead of 1110001. Why is this?
Here is the code I added and the compile-time commands.[RISCV singlecys code][1]
[The site I referred to][2]

```
///home/ubuntu4/riscv-gnu-toolchain/binutils/gdb/opcodes/riscv-opc.c
{"custom_es32",     32, INSN_CLASS_I,     "d,s,t", MATCH_CUSTOM, MASK_CUSTOM, match_opcode, 0}

~/riscv-opc.h
#define MATCH_CUSTOM_ES32 0x200006b
#define MASK_CUSTOM_ES32  0xfe00707f

DECLARE_INSN(custom, MATCH_CUSTOM_ES32, MASK_CUSTOM_ES32)
```

````
riscv64-unknown-elf-as -march=rv32im -mabi=ilp32 -o main.o main.S
riscv64-unknown-elf-as -march=rv32im -mabi=ilp32 -o startup.o startup.S
riscv64-unknown-elf-ld -static -melf32lriscv -T stdld.script startup.o main.o -o init
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -d init
~~
 220:   03ff0eeb                custom_es32     t4,t5,t6
 224:   00130313                addi    t1,t1,1
~~```


  [1]: https://github.com/ridecore/ridecore/tree/master/src/test/singlecyc/verilog
  [2]: https://hsandid.github.io/posts/risc-v-custom-instruction/
````

Comment: Opcode is the low 7 bits, you wrote `0x6b` which is `110 1011` and the func7 is the top 7 bits which you specified as `2`... Not sure how you got these values but the assembler is doing what you told it to do. Sounds like you want `0xe2000033` instead.